# coverage.py and functional testing

Tags: flask, python-unittest, coverage.py

I'm attempting to use `coverage.py` to measure code coverage when running functional tests against a Flask server instance. It failed to detect the execution of several functions in a file that I know for a fact are executed when I run my tests. This concerns me, as I had hoped to make use of coverage.py to increase the quality of my tests.

I run coverage with the following command:

```
$ coverage run --source src runserver.py
```

This starts up a test Flask server that I can successfully run requests against. In another terminal, I run my tests. My tests simulate a client and use python's `unittest` module to examine the responses to http requests that are sent to the development server. When I'm finished running the tests, I hit `ctrl+c` to stop `coverage.py` and examine the reports.

The key here is that the tests I am running are run in a command apart from `coverage.py`. These tests send requests to the development server that is being run by `coverage.py`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is that Flask (or the webserver itself) is using sub-processes to handle requests.  Read up on measuring subprocesses: http://coverage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/subprocess.html